# Java - is there something like binary stream?

Tags: java, arrays, operators

I had one question.

Is there library or etc to compose int & strings to byte array ?

Like :

```
byte temparray[] = new byte[10];

int a = 10;
int b = 10;

temparray << new String("12") << a << b;
```

Thanks.

## edit

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[649];

    byte[] charname = this.getName().getBytes();
    System.arraycopy(charname, 0 , buffer, 0, charname.length);

    for(int i=0;i<16;i++) //mystery crs 16 zeros
    {
        buffer[i+17] = (byte)0x30;
    }

    buffer[34] = this.faction;

    if(this.characterClass == 2)
    {
        buffer[40] = 2;      
    } else
    {
        buffer[40] = 1; 
    }
    System.arraycopy(BitTools.shortToByteArray(face), 0, buffer, 42, 2);
    buffer[44] = 1; 
    buffer[48] = (byte)this.characterClass; //class byte
    buffer[52] = 2; explanation yet

    buffer[54] = (byte)this.getLevel();
```

This is an example of my packet generator and i wanted to simplify it, but in packet i use only shorts, ints and strings.

Comment: `String` has an overloaded `getBytes()` which returns a byte array.

Comment: You should consider *exactly* what you want the output to be. How do you want the strings to be encoded? How do you want the integers to be encoded?

Comment: I want to simplyfy process of packet creation, but first i need to convert manually to byte an use unoptimal replace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) is a stream implementation that collects content on an internal byte array, and you can wrap it in a `java.io.OutputStreamWriter` to write character content to it.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(byteOut, "UTF-8");  // Uses UTF-8 encoding
out.write("12");
out.write(10);
out.write(10);
out.close();

byte[] bytes = byteOut.toByteArray();
```

After this, `bytes.length` is just long enough for the bytes written to `byteOut`.

Comment: Can I specify string length and if it will be shorter than 16 bytes, it will be filed with 0x00 ?

Comment: @KacperFalat, no.  There is not `snprintf` equivalent in java.  The buffer grows as needed.  If you want to NUL pad, you need to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See [java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). Note that you can wrap this stream to support writing of other types like String: `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(yourByteArrayOutputStream); pw.print("Hello");`

And afterwards use `yourByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();` to get the byte array.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

```
Integer.byteValue();
Double.byteValue();
String.getBytes();
// etc.
```

Comment: `String.getBytes()` assumes the platform encoding which is not consistently the write encoding for any one piece of code.

Comment: You will lose precision for any integer above 127 doing this.  As the java doc indicates, these calls may involve truncation.

Comment: @MikeSamuel You can always use the overloaded methods, for `String`.

Comment: Fair enough. Did a little more digging and found some better info in BigInteger.toByteArray().

"Returns a byte array containing the two's-complement representation of this BigInteger. The byte array will be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element. The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger, including at least one sign bit, which is (ceil((this.bitLength() + 1)/8)). (This representation is compatible with the (byte[]) constructor.)"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `String#getBytes` and `ByteBuffer`.  Charsets and byte order might be important depending on your use case.